# How to call action from controller using form_for helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models Customer and PriceGroup. Customer model contains field named `price_group_id`. PriceGroup model has :id field and :name filed.

I added a new action to Customer controller called `add_price_group`. When a Customer already created, I need to add a PriceGroup for him.

I used `form_for` and `select` helper.

show.html.erb listing:

```
<%= form_for @customer, url: {action: "add_price_group"}, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
            <% @customer.price_group.present? ? @row_color = "success" : @row_color = "danger" %>
            <tr class = <%= @row_color %>>
              <td><strong>Current price group</strong></td>
              <td><%= @customer.price_group.present? ? @customer.price_group.name : "Not set!"%></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <label>Choose new price group</label>
          <%= select("price_group", "id", PriceGroup.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
          <p style="margin-top:10px;"><%= f.submit "Add price group to customer", class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %></p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

customers_controller.rb listing:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @customer = Customer.new
    end

    def create
        @customer = Customer.create(customer_params)
        if @customer.errors.empty?
            redirect_to @customer
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def show
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
        @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
        if @customer.errors.empty?
            redirect_to @customer
        else
            render "edit"
        end 
    end

    def index
        @customers = Customer.all
    end

    def destroy
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
        @customer.destroy
        redirect_to customers_path
    end

    def add_price_group
        @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
    end

    private
        def customer_params
            params.require(:customer).permit(:customer_type_id, :price_group_id, :name, :short_name, :phone) 
        end
end
```

in routes.rb:

```
resources :customers do
    post :add_price_group, :on => :collection
  end
  resources :price_groups
```

All I need is to update price_group_id field in Customer model.

I'm a new in Rails and can't understand how to use all these code together. Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `form` where you have:

```
<%= select("price_group", "id", PriceGroup.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
```

Change it to this and try:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:price_group_id, PriceGroup.all, :id, :name, { :class=>'form-control' }) %>
```

It will automatically include the selected `price_group_id` in the params and your controller will save it in the customer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shows mistake Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=add_price_group
UPDATE

Comment: Where did you put this code, please update your question with the new code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! In

```
<%= form_for @customer, url: {action: "add_price_group"}, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
```

correct is

```
<%= form_for @customer, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
```